# add markers to leaflet map from results of ajax call - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'lat' of null

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have a leaflet map on which you click to add a marker, then you can click on a link in the popup which calls an ajax query. The query basically searches for incidents within 5k of the original marker. All of this is working fine.

I then want to take the results and add new markers (probably in a different colour to the original) and add them to the map. I am getting the results but I am struggling to parse the object and therefore cannot add the markers to the map. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

The results arrive in this format

```
[{'Incident_ID': 26944, 'wkt': 'POINT (-1.375239 50.908906)'}, {'Incident_ID': 27509, 'wkt':'POINT (-1.375228 50.908886)'}, {'Incident_ID': 27430, 'wkt': 'POINT (-1.373876 50.908886)'}]
```

And my JS is here:

```
var map = L.map('map1').setView([50.937832, -1.470623], 10);
<!--add map to display>-->
L.tileLayer('https://api.os.uk/maps/raster/v1/zxy/Light_3857/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?xxxxxxx', {
    attribution: '&copy; Crown copyright and database rights ' + new Date().getFullYear() + ' Ordnance Survey.',
    maxZoom: 20,
    minZoom: 7
}).addTo(map);
$("#clear").click(function() {
    map.removeLayer(marker)
    });
var marker = null;
            
map.on('click', function (e) {
    if (marker !== null) {
        map.removeLayer(marker);
    }
    marker = L.marker(e.latlng, {
        title: "Start Point",
        //draggable: true,
    }).addTo(map);
    var coords = "point({latitude:toFloat('" + e.latlng.lat.toString() +"'), longitude:toFloat('"+ e.latlng.lng.toString() +"')})";
    var link = $('<a href="#" class="showgraph">'+coords+'</a>').on('click', { value: coords }, function(x) {
                stuff = $.ajax({
                    url: 'http://localhost:8080/demo/geosearch/' + coords,
                    type: 'GET',
                    dataType: 'json' ,
                })
                .done(function( json ) {
                        obj = JSON.parse(stuff.responseText);
                        var n;
                        for (n in obj) {
                            L.marker(omnivore.wkt.parse(obj[n].wkt)).addTo(map);
                            //wkts.push(obj[n].wkt);
                        }
                    })
            });
    var div = $('<div />').text('Incidents within 5km of: ').append(link)[0];
    marker.bindPopup(div);
});
```

In chrome developer tools I'm seeing this error:

```
leaflet.js:5 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'lat' of null
at Object.project (leaflet.js:5)
at Object.latLngToPoint (leaflet.js:5)
at e.project (leaflet.js:5)
at e.latLngToLayerPoint (leaflet.js:5)
at e.update (leaflet.js:7)
at e.onAdd (leaflet.js:7)
at e._layerAdd (leaflet.js:6)
at e.whenReady (leaflet.js:6)
at e.addLayer (leaflet.js:6)
at e.addTo (leaflet.js:6)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to create a layer group in which to add the new markers

```
var markers = L.layerGroup();
```

and add the markers to the group

```
markers.addLayer(marker);
markers.addTo(map)
```